# Join a Tree Based Table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a fact table "**Pricing**" like this:

| Serial | Main_Category | Group_Category | Sub_Category | Item | Location | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Clothes | Men | T Shirts | T Shirt 1 | Store 1 | 100 |
| 2 | Clothes | Men | T Shirts | T Shirt 1 | All | 25 |
| 3 | Devices | TVs | Smart TVs | SmartTV 1 | Store 1 | 50 |
| 4 | Devices | TVs | Smart TVs | All | Store 1 | 75 |

You can note that not all items are explicitly defined, if the item is not mentioned, it should be available in the "**All**".

"**All**" could be found in any column except for **Price**

Another dimension table "**Sales**" like this:

| Serial | Main_Category | Group_Category | Sub_Category | Item | Location |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Clothes | Men | T Shirts | T Shirt 1 | Store 1 |
| 2 | Clothes | Men | T Shirts | T Shirt 1 | Store 3 |
| 3 | Devices | TVs | Smart TVs | SmartTV 3 | Store 1 |
| 4 | Devices | TVs | Smart TVs | SmartTV 1 | Store 1 |

I would like to add the price from the **Pricing** table to the **Sales** table without using a join for each combination

Excepted output:

| Serial | Main_Category | Group_Category | Sub_Category | Item | Location | Price |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Clothes | Men | T Shirts | T Shirt 1 | Store 1 | 100 |
| 2 | Clothes | Men | T Shirts | T Shirt 1 | Store 3 | 25 |
| 3 | Devices | TVs | Smart TVs | SmartTV 3 | Store 1 | 75 |
| 4 | Devices | TVs | Smart TVs | SmartTV 1 | Store 1 | 50 |

**Update:**
"All" could be found in more than one column

Comment: Why don't you want to  `without using a join for each combination`?

Comment: What about there are two the same match rows between  `Sales` and `Pricing` tables?

Comment: @D-Shih I will update the question, "**All**" could be found in more than one column. I think the number of combinations will be very large

Comment: @D-Shih Could you please refer to the two same match rows?

Comment: A row from  the `Sales` could match a number of `Pricing`'s, for example `Pricing.( Item, Location)` = `( SmartTV 1, All)` and `(All, Store 1)`. What is the logic to select exactly one pricing?

Comment: @Serg, if so, select the one with the minimum serial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do

```
select *
from (
    select s.*, p.Price, row_number() over(partition by s.Main_Category, .., s.Location order by p.Serial) rn
    from Sales s
    join Pricing p on 
      (s.Main_Category = p.Main_Category or p.Main_Category ='All')
      and ..
      and (s.Location = p.Location or p.Location ='All')
 ) t
 where rn = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I used to create a join for each condition in your join and my actual tables are larger than the above example. Really appreciated.